# I copied the css content from a css url to a .css file but now the icons are not showing

Tags: php, css

here is the css url where you can find the css code that I copied to a .css file:

https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lightgallery/1.3.9/css/lightgallery.min.css

Comment: you can create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead of the code that doesnt work instead of linking us to a HUGE page full of codes. And did you know formatting your code will make it much easier for us to read?

Answer (score 0):

You missed adding the fonts which are in your CSS and I also mention in below

```
@font-face {
    font-family: lg;
    src: url(../fonts/lg.eot?n1z373);
    src: url(../fonts/lg.eot?#iefixn1z373) format("embedded-opentype"), url(../fonts/lg.woff?n1z373) format("woff"), url(../fonts/lg.ttf?n1z373) format("truetype"), url(../fonts/lg.svg?n1z373#lg) format("svg");
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal
}
```